# $(f(z+h) - f(z))/h$ converges uniformly as $h \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

Let's denote $D_x = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| < x \} $.

Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $D_R$ then I want to prove that for any $0 < r < R$  a function $\displaystyle{\frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}}$ uniformly converges to $f'(z)$ on $D_r$.

My attempt goes as follows. Without loss of generality we can assume $|h| < |q| < R - r$. We represent $f(z) = \displaystyle{\sum a_nz^n}$ and then

$f(z+h) - f(z) - hf'(z) = \displaystyle{\sum a_n(z+h)^n - \sum a_nz^n - h \sum na_nz^{n-1}} = h^2 g(z,h)$.
Since $|z+h| < |z| + |h| < R$ by our assumption on $h$ we conclude that all series converge in $D_r$. Thus

$$\left| \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} - f'(z)\right| = |h||g(z,h)|$$

and this is almost it except that I don't know that $g(z,h)$ is bounded. I am sure it is continuous on $\bar D_r \times  \bar D_q$ as a function of two variables but it looks like a of work to check this.

So can my approach work or it's easier to do it in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest a different approach. For $z, z+h \in D_R$ is (integrating along the straight segment from $z$ to $z+h$)
$$
 f(z+h) -f(z) = \int_z^{z+h} f'(w) \, dw = h \int_0^1 f'(z + th) \, dt \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} - f'(z) = \int_0^1( f'(z + th) -f'(z))\, dt
$$
$f'$ is continuous, and therefore uniformly continuous on any closed disk with radius $r < R$. This shows that the right-hand side converges uniformly to zero for $h \to 0$ on that closed disk.

Comment: So actually we don't even need to assume it's holomorphic?

Comment: @Vladislav: The first identity holds because $f$ is complex differentiable. And the continuity of $f'$ is also a consequence of the holomorphy of $f$ (via Cauchy's integral formula).

Comment: but we could replace it being holomorphcic by being $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, though

Comment: @Vladislav: With $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ both $z$ and $h$ become *vectors* in $\Bbb R^2$ and you can not even divide by $h$.