# $f$ is holomorphic in $U(z_0,\delta)$ $\implies\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(z_n)-f(w_n)}{z_n-w_n}}=f'(z_0)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $U(z_0,\delta)$ and $z_n\to z_0,w_n\to z_0\ (n\to\infty), z_n\neq w_n$,
then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(z_n)-f(w_n)}{z_n-w_n}=f'(z_0).$$

Unlike in real analysis, we can't use MVT (MVT is not ture for holomorphic functions).
I can prove the result by using power series expansion as follows: WLG, we can suppose $z_0=0$,
and then $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k,\quad z\in U(0,\delta).$$
$$f(z_n)-f(w_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\left(z^k_n-w^k_n\right)
=a_1(z_n-w_n)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k\left(z^k_n-w^k_n\right).$$
We need only to prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k\left(z^k_n-w^k_n\right)}{z_n-w_n}=0,$$
which is not difficult by using the umiform convergence.

If there is another method such as $\epsilon-N$ language.

Any help or hints will be welcomed.

Comment: you can use Cauchy noting that $\frac{f(z_n)-f(w_n)}{z_n-w_n}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0| \le \delta}\frac{f(\zeta)d\zeta}{(z_n-\zeta)(w_n-\zeta)}$ and take the limit in the integral by DCT say so get $f'(z_0)$ by Cauchy again; note that some kind of uniformity is needed because the result is not true in general for real functions unless they have a continuous derivative, so somewhere you need to use that complex differentiability (on open sets) implies continuous (and of course more) derivative and Cauchy is one such way, power series is another etc

Comment: @Conrad Nice comment.Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4662888/42969

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

It is a fact that even if we do not have the MVT equality, we still have the MVT inequality. That is

$$|g(a) - g(b)| \le |b-a| \cdot \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |g'(t)|$$

Now consider the function
$$g(z) = f(z) - (z-z_0)f'(z_0)$$

So what we end up using is the continuity of the derivative of $f$. So the proof works for functions of class $C^{1}$ in many contexts. Good luck with the details!